# How to Find and group Duplicates in MS Access 2010?

Tags: duplicates

I'm trying to find duplicate entries across 2 columns in Access 2010 and group them together without affecting the data integrity(I have 20 columns in total and 2 of them contain duplicates in random rows). I would like the rows that contain duplicates be lined up.

I have this formula for finding the duplicates but it doesn't seem to work and doesn't group the duplicates anyhow.

```
SELECT t.IsParent, tbl.*
FROM (SELECT 
     parent.id , 1 AS IsParent, parent.[company url] as Col
FROM 
    tbl AS child INNER JOIN tbl AS parent ON child.domain_name = parent.[company url]
WHERE (((parent.domain_name)<>[parent].[company url]))
union all
SELECT 
    child.id , 0 AS IsParent,  child.[company url] as Col
FROM 
    tbl AS child INNER JOIN tbl AS parent ON child.domain_name = parent.[company url]
WHERE (((parent.domain_name)<>[parent].[company url]))
)  AS t INNER JOIN tbl ON t.id = tbl.id;
```

I would highly appreciate help in solving this issue.

Thank you